# build failed a lot of errors springboot maven launching on intelleji

Tags: angular, spring-boot, intellij-idea, build, compiler-errors

Today I am here to give you my solution following a very strange problem that I had.

**when I launched or i was building springboot, i got an error number ranging from 10 to 100.**

**This is the error :**

[image]

Whenever I searched for an answer I ran into someone who said they were missing an dependency.
This is not true because before uploading the data to git it was working.

My solution is below

Answer (score 0):

**There are two solutions to this problem :**

1- Copy and remove the divder "parent" in your pom.xml and load maven changes.(ctrl+maj+O). After that, paste the divider "parent" at the same place and load maven changes again.

2- Same technique but with the divider "version" in the diviser "parent"

it works 95% of the time.

If this does not work, try again.

You can always run the "mvn clean install" command if it still doesn't work.